# Scrape opening odds from Oddsportal page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the opening odds from Oddsportal website for a specific page:
[https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/serie-b/gremio-cruzeiro-WhMMpc7f/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jldn6.jpg)

To do that I am using the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/serie-b/gremio-cruzeiro-WhMMpc7f/')
sleep(2)

element=driver.find_element(By.ID,'odds-data-table').find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'table- container').find_element(By.XPATH,"//table[@class='table-main detail-odds sortable']").find_element(By.XPATH,'//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')

hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
hover.perform()
sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.ID,'tooltipdiv')
```

Although,the ActionChains object is getting created, the driver is unable to find the element 'tooltipdiv' after the action.

To give some context, 'tooltipdiv' element only appears on the page when the cursor moves to the element in the ActionChains object.

[click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jldn6.jpg)

I have even tried 'click_and_hold', 'click' methods, but none of them seem to be working.
I am not sure what has changed but the same script used to work a couple of months back.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is matter of fine tuning it a bit using explicit wait and proper xpath and expected condition it will work smoothly. There are 3-4 problems as below

1. The cookies policy popup need to be handled at least for me.
2. The find_element(*) function chain was breaking due to extra space in you class name as `'table- container'`
3. Instead of `ActionChains()`, simple `click()` worked for me.
4. Again post click action wait for tooltip element to be clickable since it make some changes in the DOM based on mouse action.

Below is the working code post fixing -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/serie-b/gremio-cruzeiro-WhMMpc7f/')

# 1.initialize explicit wait and click on the element
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//button[@id='onetrust-reject-all-handler']"))).click()

# 2 & 3 find element with clickable state to perform action
element = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='table-container']//table[@class='table-main detail-odds sortable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")))
element.click()

# 3. wait for the element and grab the text of tooltip
tooltip = wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tooltipdiv")))
print(tooltip.text)
```

**Output**

```
21 Aug, 18:56 1.92 -0.10
21 Aug, 18:36 2.02 -0.04
21 Aug, 18:19 2.06 +0.05
21 Aug, 15:23 2.01 +0.03
21 Aug, 14:51 1.98 -0.02
21 Aug, 14:31 2.00 -0.15
21 Aug, 09:38 2.15 -0.03
20 Aug, 14:51 2.18 +0.04
20 Aug, 01:12 2.14 -0.09
20 Aug, 01:07 2.23 +0.08
19 Aug, 23:00 2.15 +0.01
19 Aug, 14:01 2.14 +0.02
19 Aug, 11:07 2.12 -0.05
19 Aug, 10:58 2.17 +0.07
19 Aug, 10:56 2.10 -0.07
19 Aug, 09:54 2.17 +0.07
19 Aug, 01:14 2.10 -0.07
19 Aug, 01:12 2.17 +0.07
19 Aug, 00:59 2.10 -0.13
18 Aug, 17:45 2.23 +0.04
```